# Why can't open the svg file with inkscape?

Tags: svg, inkscape

There is a svg file ,i can show it with chrome.

[svg file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfnv344q0pv4wi5/gen.svg?dl=0)

Why can see nothing when to import it(please download it form dropbox and save it as gen.svg) with  inkscape?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This svg includes a PNG-File instead of SVG path or fill instructions, where Inkscape is made for:

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="880px" height="919px" viewBox="0 0 880 919" enable-background="new 0 0 880 919" xml:space="preserve">  <image id="image0" width="880" height="919" x="0" y="0"
    href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA3AAAAOXCAIAAADqyTS6AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN
AAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAACA
AElEQVR42uz995sj2XXnCX/PDQeXyMzypqurq71h03uRlEhKlKVGErWa0c7MzuzO+0ftM7O7MyPD
...
ODowMKFcwFEAAAAldEVYdGRhdGU6bW9kaWZ5ADIwMjAtMDQtMTFUMTY6MTc6MjQrMDg6MDDQAXjt
AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" />
</svg>
```

Comment: That alone is no reason for not rendering it.

Comment: You are right. It depends on several things ;) e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216376/inkscape-not-fully-converting-png-into-svg/22217334. But for these operations I use gimp.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the image isn't linked correctly. Use

xlink:href

instead of

href

Comment: Well it is correct (for SVG 2). It's just that inkscape doesn't yet support this SVG 2 feature.